# How do I acknowledge a Stripe event in C# immediately but still process it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, stripe-payments

Under Stripe best practices for webhooks it states:

*If your webhook script performs complex logic, or makes network calls, it’s possible that the script would time out before Stripe sees its complete execution. Ideally, your webhook handler code (acknowledging receipt of an event by returning a 2xx status code) is separate of any other logic you do for that event.*

In C# how do I return a 200 response immediately and then carry out some other processing?

Comment: From server send a Request with 200 OK.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2790392e-5648-4f57-8427-efa0607a9883/responding-to-a-http-message-from-a-console-application?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to use Task object. In BackendProcessing() write any custom logic you need. HttpStatusCode.OK will return 200.

```js
    public IHttpActionResult YouApiMethod()
    {
        var customLogic = new[]
        {
            Task.Run(() => BackendProcessing())
        };

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me because injected services get disposed before BackendProcessing() has completed.